# BottomNavigationView : unable to destroy activity java.lang.illegalargumentexception FragmentContainerView does not have a NavController

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation

We have the bellow crash which is only reported against Android 9.

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: View androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView{4376b50 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-720,1008 #7f08010e app:id/fragment_top_container} does not have a NavController set
       at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.kt:71)
       at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onDestroyView(NavHostFragment.kt:330)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performDestroyView(Fragment.java:3232)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.destroyFragmentView(FragmentStateManager.java:744)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:327)
       at androidx.fragment.app.SpecialEffectsController$FragmentStateManagerOperation.complete(SpecialEffectsController.java:771)
       at androidx.fragment.app.SpecialEffectsController$Operation.cancel(SpecialEffectsController.java:615)
       at androidx.fragment.app.SpecialEffectsController.forceCompleteAllOperations(SpecialEffectsController.java:350)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2844)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:2820)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchDestroy(FragmentController.java:345)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:306)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onDestroy(AppCompatActivity.java:278)
       at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:7724)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1310)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4726)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4764)
       at android.app.servertransaction.DestroyActivityItem.execute(DestroyActivityItem.java:39)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1970)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

I alredy checked all the answers and I can see that we respect all of them.

Here is how the `BottomNavigationBar` is used withen the `MenuActivity` :

```
class MenuActivity : BaseActivity() {

    private var currentNavController: LiveData<NavController>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu)
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            setupBottomNavigationBar()
        }

        obtainViewModel().getNumberToSend()
        obtainViewModel().unreadCount.observe(this) {
            val badge: BadgeDrawable =
                findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomMenu).getOrCreateBadge(R.id.instruction)
            badge.number = it
            badge.backgroundColor = getColor(R.color.colorIconWarning)
            badge.isVisible = it > 0
        }
        obtainViewModel().sizeEventToSend.observe(this) {
            val badge: BadgeDrawable =
                findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomMenu).getOrCreateBadge(R.id.event)
            badge.number = it
            badge.backgroundColor = getColor(R.color.colorIconWarning)
            badge.isVisible = it > 0
        }
        obtainViewModel().sizeReleveToSend.observe(this) {
            val badge: BadgeDrawable =
                findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomMenu).getOrCreateBadge(R.id.round)
            badge.number = it
            badge.backgroundColor = getColor(R.color.colorIconWarning)
            badge.isVisible = it > 0
        }

        analytics.setUserPropertySite()
    }

    private fun setupBottomNavigationBar() {
        val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomMenu)

        val navGraphIds = listOf(R.navigation.round, R.navigation.event, R.navigation.instruction)

        val controller = bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(
            navGraphIds = navGraphIds,
            fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager,
            containerId = R.id.fragment_top_container,
            intent = intent
        )

        controller.observe(this) { navController ->
            setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
            navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
                bottomNavigationView.menu.getItem(0).isEnabled =
                    !(destination.id == R.id.navigation_round || destination.id == R.id.navigation_releve || destination.id == R.id.navigation_indicateurs)
                bottomNavigationView.menu.getItem(1).isEnabled =
                    !(destination.id == R.id.navigation_book_shift || destination.id == R.id.navigation_event)
                bottomNavigationView.menu.getItem(2).isEnabled =
                    destination.id != R.id.navigation_instructions
            }
        }
        currentNavController = controller
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        setupBottomNavigationBar()
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return currentNavController?.value?.navigateUp() ?: false
    }

    private fun obtainViewModel(): MenuViewModel = obtainViewModel(MenuViewModel::class.java)

    companion object {

        const val TIME_BETWEEN_DOUBLE_CLICK = 1000L

        fun createIntent(context: Context) =
            Intent(context, MenuActivity::class.java)
    }
}
```

And bellow is the `NavigationExtensions.kt` :

```
/**
 * Manages the various graphs needed for a [BottomNavigationView].
 *
 * This sample is a workaround until the Navigation Component supports multiple back stacks.
 */
fun BottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(
    navGraphIds: List<Int>,
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    containerId: Int,
    intent: Intent
): LiveData<NavController> {

    // Map of tags
    val graphIdToTagMap = SparseArray<String>()
    // Result. Mutable live data with the selected controlled
    val selectedNavController = MutableLiveData<NavController>()

    var firstFragmentGraphId = 0

    // First create a NavHostFragment for each NavGraph ID
    navGraphIds.forEachIndexed { index, navGraphId ->
        val fragmentTag = getFragmentTag(index)

        // Find or create the Navigation host fragment
        val navHostFragment = obtainNavHostFragment(
            fragmentManager,
            fragmentTag,
            navGraphId,
            containerId
        )

        // Obtain its id
        val graphId = navHostFragment.navController.graph.id

        if (index == 0) {
            firstFragmentGraphId = graphId
        }

        // Save to the map
        graphIdToTagMap[graphId] = fragmentTag

        // Attach or detach nav host fragment depending on whether it's the selected item.
        if (this.selectedItemId == graphId) {
            // Update livedata with the selected graph
            selectedNavController.value = navHostFragment.navController
            attachNavHostFragment(fragmentManager, navHostFragment, index == 0)
        } else {
            detachNavHostFragment(fragmentManager, navHostFragment)
        }
    }

    // Now connect selecting an item with swapping Fragments
    var selectedItemTag = graphIdToTagMap[this.selectedItemId]
    val firstFragmentTag = graphIdToTagMap[firstFragmentGraphId]
    var isOnFirstFragment = selectedItemTag == firstFragmentTag

    // When a navigation item is selected
    setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        // Don't do anything if the state is state has already been saved.
        if (fragmentManager.isStateSaved) {
            false
        } else {
            val newlySelectedItemTag = graphIdToTagMap[item.itemId]
            if (selectedItemTag != newlySelectedItemTag) {
                // Pop everything above the first fragment (the "fixed start destination")
                fragmentManager.popBackStack(
                    firstFragmentTag,
                    FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE
                )
                val selectedFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(newlySelectedItemTag)
                        as NavHostFragment

                // Exclude the first fragment tag because it's always in the back stack.
                if (firstFragmentTag != newlySelectedItemTag) {
                    // Commit a transaction that cleans the back stack and adds the first fragment
                    // to it, creating the fixed started destination.
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(
                            R.anim.nav_default_enter_anim,
                            R.anim.nav_default_exit_anim,
                            R.anim.nav_default_pop_enter_anim,
                            R.anim.nav_default_pop_exit_anim
                        )
                        .attach(selectedFragment)
                        .setPrimaryNavigationFragment(selectedFragment)
                        .apply {
                            // Detach all other Fragments
                            graphIdToTagMap.forEach { _, fragmentTagIter ->
                                if (fragmentTagIter != newlySelectedItemTag) {
                                    detach(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(firstFragmentTag)!!)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .addToBackStack(firstFragmentTag)
                        .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                        .commit()
                }
                selectedItemTag = newlySelectedItemTag
                isOnFirstFragment = selectedItemTag == firstFragmentTag
                selectedNavController.value = selectedFragment.navController
                true
            } else {
                false
            }
        }
    }

    // Optional: on item reselected, pop back stack to the destination of the graph
    setupItemReselected(graphIdToTagMap, fragmentManager)

    // Handle deep link
    setupDeepLinks(navGraphIds, fragmentManager, containerId, intent)

    // Finally, ensure that we update our BottomNavigationView when the back stack changes
    fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener {
        if (!isOnFirstFragment && !fragmentManager.isOnBackStack(firstFragmentTag)) {
            this.selectedItemId = firstFragmentGraphId
        }

        // Reset the graph if the currentDestination is not valid (happens when the back
        // stack is popped after using the back button).
        selectedNavController.value?.let { controller ->
            if (controller.currentDestination == null) {
                controller.navigate(controller.graph.id)
            }
        }
    }
    return selectedNavController
}

private fun BottomNavigationView.setupDeepLinks(
    navGraphIds: List<Int>,
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    containerId: Int,
    intent: Intent
) {
    navGraphIds.forEachIndexed { index, navGraphId ->
        val fragmentTag = getFragmentTag(index)

        // Find or create the Navigation host fragment
        val navHostFragment = obtainNavHostFragment(
            fragmentManager,
            fragmentTag,
            navGraphId,
            containerId
        )
        // Handle Intent
        if (navHostFragment.navController.handleDeepLink(intent)
            && selectedItemId != navHostFragment.navController.graph.id
        ) {
            this.selectedItemId = navHostFragment.navController.graph.id
        }
    }
}

private fun BottomNavigationView.setupItemReselected(
    graphIdToTagMap: SparseArray<String>,
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager
) {
    setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener { item ->
        val newlySelectedItemTag = graphIdToTagMap[item.itemId]
        val selectedFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(newlySelectedItemTag)
                as NavHostFragment
        val navController = selectedFragment.navController
        // Pop the back stack to the start destination of the current navController graph
        navController.popBackStack(
            navController.graph.startDestinationId, false
        )
    }
}

private fun detachNavHostFragment(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    navHostFragment: NavHostFragment
) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .detach(navHostFragment)
        .commitNow()
}

private fun attachNavHostFragment(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    navHostFragment: NavHostFragment,
    isPrimaryNavFragment: Boolean
) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .attach(navHostFragment)
        .apply {
            if (isPrimaryNavFragment) {
                setPrimaryNavigationFragment(navHostFragment)
            }
        }
        .commitNow()

}

private fun obtainNavHostFragment(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    fragmentTag: String,
    navGraphId: Int,
    containerId: Int
): NavHostFragment {
    // If the Nav Host fragment exists, return it
    val existingFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag) as NavHostFragment?
    existingFragment?.let { return it }

    // Otherwise, create it and return it.
    val navHostFragment = NavHostFragment.create(navGraphId)
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .add(containerId, navHostFragment, fragmentTag)
        .commitNow()
    return navHostFragment
}

private fun FragmentManager.isOnBackStack(backStackName: String): Boolean {
    val backStackCount = backStackEntryCount
    for (index in 0 until backStackCount) {
        if (getBackStackEntryAt(index).name == backStackName) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

private fun getFragmentTag(index: Int) = "bottomNavigation#$index"
```

Comment: Upload your fragment_top_container.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue is on the layout file, It will be easier if you could upload the layout file. Most of the time the "does not have a NavController set" crash meets because of the `<FrameLayout>`,

Actually, Navigation can't find NavController in FrameLayout. So replacing `<FrameLayout>` with `<fragment>` will make it work if you have added the navigation parent view as `<FrameLayout>`.

And make sure you add the fragment name inside the tag as NaviHost as below.

```
android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
```

Hope this will help.